# Replace new line (\n) character in csv file - spark scala

Tags: scala, replace, apache-spark, character, newline

Just to illustrate the problem I have taken a testset csv file. But in real case scenario, the problem has to handle more than a TeraByte data.

I have a CSV file, where the columns are enclosed by quotes("col1"). But when the data import was done. One column contains new line character(\n). This is leading me to lot of problems, when I want to save them as Hive tables.

My idea was to replace the \n character with "|" pipe in spark.

I achieved so far :

```
1. val test = sqlContext.load(
        "com.databricks.spark.csv",
        Map("path" -> "test_set.csv", "header" -> "true", "inferSchema" -> "true", "delimiter" -> "," , "quote" -> "\"", "escape" -> "\\" ,"parserLib" -> "univocity" ))#read a csv file

 2.   val dataframe = test.toDF() #convert to dataframe

  3.    dataframe.foreach(println) #print

    4. dataframe.map(row => {
        val row4 = row.getAs[String](4)
        val make = row4.replaceAll("[\r\n]", "|") 
        (make)
      }).collect().foreach(println) #replace not working for me
```

Sample set :

```
(17 , D73 ,525, 1  ,testing\n    ,  90 ,20.07.2011 ,null ,F10 , R)
 (17 , D73 ,526, 1  ,null         ,  89 ,20.07.2011 ,null ,F10 , R)
 (17 , D73 ,529, 1  ,once \n again,  10 ,20.07.2011 ,null ,F10 , R)
 (17 , D73 ,531, 1  ,test3\n      ,  10 ,20.07.2011 ,null ,F10 , R)
```

Expected result set :

```
(17 , D73 ,525, 1  ,testing|    ,  90 ,20.07.2011 ,null ,F10 , R)
 (17 , D73 ,526, 1  ,null         ,  89 ,20.07.2011 ,null ,F10 , R)
 (17 , D73 ,529, 1  ,once | again,  10 ,20.07.2011 ,null ,F10 , R)
 (17 , D73 ,531, 1  ,test3|      ,  10 ,20.07.2011 ,null ,F10 , R)
```

what worked for me:

```
val rep = "\n123\n Main Street\n".replaceAll("[\\r\\n]", "|") rep: String = |123| Main Street|
```

but why I am not able to do on Tuple basis?

```
 val dataRDD = lines_wo_header.map(line => line.split(";")).map(row => (row(0).toLong, row(1).toString, 
                                               row(2).toLong, row(3).toLong, 
                                               row(4).toString, row(5).toLong,
                                               row(6).toString, row(7).toString, row(8).toString,row(9).toString)) 

dataRDD.map(row => {
                val wert = row._5.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]", "|") 
                (row._1,row._2,row._3,row._4,wert,row._6, row._7,row._8,row._9,row._10)
                }).collect().foreach(println)
```

> Spark --version 1.3.1

Comment: replaceAll("[\\r\\n]", "|") is replacing all 'r' and 'n' character to '|' while we want to replace only new line character(\n).

Answer (score 8):

If you can use Spark SQL 1.5 or higher, you may consider using the [functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) available for columns. Assuming you don't know (or don't have) the names for the columns, you can do as in the following snippet:

```
val df = test.toDF()

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val newDF = df.withColumn(df.columns(4), regexp_replace(col(df.columns(4)), "[\\r\\n]", "|"))
```

If you know the name of the column, you can replace `df.columns(4)` by its name in both occurences.

I hope that helps.
Cheers.

Comment: thx, unfortunately i have no DataFrame API. Need to work it with RDDs.

Comment: @user3560220 you can work with the dataframe and convert it back to RDD later by calling `newDF.rdd` or `newDF.map`

Comment: I tried your solution, but the "\n" characters were  not replaced. How could you solve it. ? Anything I am missing ?

Comment: Actually, in my tests even your solution works. Maybe it's something in your data? Is it raising an error or it just doesn't replace?

Comment: @DanieldePaula: I tried the solution as suggested by you and tried to output my file locally using standalone spark in windows. When I open in Notepad++, it always shows CRLF at the end of each line with the settings --> view symbol enabled. I was actually expecting the CRLF to go away using the replace function. Am I missing something here? `regexp_replace(ColName, "[\\r\\n]", "") as trimmed_column`

Comment: @DanieldePaula, regexp_replace(col(df.columns(4)), "[\\r\\n]", "|") is replacing all 'n' and 'r' characters to '|' . while I only want to replace new line character(\n).

Comment: @Daniel de Paula.. Is it possible to add \r\n at the end of each record, when spark write dataframe as csv.. by default its is writing with '\n' only.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67090580/linesep-option-with-spark-2-4

Answer (score 0):

> My idea was to replace the \n character with "|" pipe in spark.

I tried **replaceAll** method but it is not working. Here is an alternative to achieve the same:

```
val test = sq.load(
        "com.databricks.spark.csv",
        Map("path" -> "file:///home/veda/sample.csv", "header" -> "false", "inferSchema" -> "true", "delimiter" -> "," , "quote" -> "\"", "escape" -> "\\" ,"parserLib" -> "univocity" ))

val dataframe = test.toDF()

val mapped = dataframe.map({
    row => {
    val str = row.get(0).toString()
    var fnal=new StringBuilder(str)
    //replace newLine 
    var newLineIndex=fnal.indexOf("\\n")
    while(newLineIndex != -1){
        fnal.replace(newLineIndex,newLineIndex+2,"|")
        newLineIndex = fnal.indexOf("\\n")                  
    }

    //replace carriage returns
    var cgIndex=fnal.indexOf("\\r")
    while(cgIndex != -1){
        fnal.replace(cgIndex,cgIndex+2,"|")
        cgIndex = fnal.indexOf("\\r")                   
    }

    (fnal.toString()) //tuple modified

    }
})

mapped.collect().foreach(println)
```

Note: You might want to move the duplicate code to separate function.

Answer (score 0):

The multi line support for CSV is added in spark version 2.2 [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19610) and spark 2.2 is not yet released.

I had faced same issue and resolved it with the help us hadoop input format and reader.

Copy InputFormat and reader classes from [git](https://github.com/benleon/NewLineRemover/blob/master/MultiLine/src/org/apache/ben/FileCleaningInputFormat.java) and implement like this:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

//implementation

 JavaPairRDD<LongWritable, Text> rdd =
                context.
                        newAPIHadoopFile(path, FileCleaningInputFormat.class, null, null, new Configuration());
JavaRDD<String> inputWithMultiline= rdd.map(s -> s._2().toString())
```

**Another solution**- use `CSVInputFormat` from Apache crunch to read CSV file then parse each CSV line using opencsv:

```
sparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile(path, CSVInputFormat.class, null, null, new Configuration()).map(s -> s._2().toString());
```

Apache crunch maven dependency:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.crunch</groupId>
      <artifactId>crunch-core</artifactId>
      <version>0.15.0</version>
  </dependency>
```