# lineSep option with Spark 2.4

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Is `lineSep` option really works with Spark 2.4 version.

```
lineSep (default covers all \r, \r\n and \n): defines the line separator that should be used for parsing. Maximum length is 1 character.
```

I am writing a Dataframe to GCS bucket location but its always writing it with line separator as `'\n'` only.

```
df
  .select("COLLECTTIME","SITE","NETWORK")
  .coalesce(1)
  .limit(10)
  .write
  .option("header", false)
  .option("compression", "gzip")
  .option("lineSep","\r\n")
  .csv(tmpOutput)
```

I was looking for `CRLF` at the end of each line.

I tried below as well but not working

```
df2.withColumn(df2.columns.last,concat(col(df2.columns.last),lit("\r")))
  .write
  .option("header", false)
  .option("compression", "gzip")
  .csv(tmpOutput)
```

I tried below as well but no luck.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df2.withColumn(df2.columns.last,regexp_replace(col(df2.columns.last),"[\\r]","[\\r\\n]"))
  .write
  .option("header", false)
  .option("compression", "gzip")
  .csv(tmpOutput)
```

Now I am thinking to read file again from `GCS` once its written and read it line by line and append '\r' at the end of each record. isn't something short and simple available with `Spark 2.4`. I just need to have `'CRLF'` at the end of each record.

read and update is also not possible since objects stored on gcs buckets are immutable. I cannot keep files on buffer since they little bigger in size as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am very sorry, but AFAIK, I am afraid that Spark allows the different separators you cited in your question:

```
lineSep (default covers all \r, \r\n and \n): defines the line separator that should be used for parsing. Maximum length is 1 character.
```

only for reading, but not for writing; in the later case, either `\n` is hardcoded or, since Spark versions `2.4` and `3.0`, you can choose a custom line separator but limited to a single character.

Please, consider read [this Github issue](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/23080), it provides the whole background about the problem. [This other one](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/18304) could be helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks.. I will go through with these links...we have a req to read from gcs bucket and add a line sep as crlf... I tried few other things with Scala and python

Comment: You are welcome @vikrantrana. I see mate... I am very sorry for not being able to provide you a better approach. I hope you can find a better solution

Comment: It seems that my client is adamant to have CRLF in the file.. Is there any way we can do this.. any pointer in python or Scala without Spark.. I tried some workaround but doesn't seems to work. one way I think is using shell but for that I have to bring files to my local and than upload it back to GCS location. Can I hold and update files at some temporary location with in reach of Dataproc cluster?

Comment: Hi @vikrantrana. I am sorry to hear that. Well, it is difficult to say: please, can you describe in more detail your use case? Where does your data come from? Should it be transformed in any way in addition to the csv conversion? Do you need to use Dataproc mandatorily? In a Dataproc cluster you have the option to use HDFS in addition to GCS, perhaps you can use it for temporary computations and then modify the file adjusting the line ending to fit your needs prior to uploading it to GCS. But please, can you provide some information related to these questions?

Comment: For instance, with Python and Pandas, you have the ability of [export a dataframe to csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) choosing the `line_terminator`(`rn` in your case). It can be used standalone in addition to the gcs client or integrated with other products like, for example, Apache Beam (Dataflow in GCP) which provides batch and streaming data processing capabilities. Please, consider read [this article](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/transform-json-to-csv-from-google-bucket-using-a-dataflow-python-pipeline-92906c87cc96), (cont)

Comment: it illustrates this concept. Depending on your use case these solutions can be or not useful.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. I have a spark job which runs on Dataproc cluster, which reads from bigquery table and write output to GCS bucket location which by defaults writes with '\n' only. I have a req to write it with '\r\n'. options available are Python,Scala and Spark

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @vikrantrana, I just realized your comment. Yeah, I see. The problem is again the limitation mentioned in the answer. If your dataset is small, perhaps one thing you can try - I never tried it before, but it may work in your use case - is to convert your dataframe [toPandas](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas) and customize the line delimiter of the [`to_csv` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) as indicated in a previous comment.

Comment: In order to make it work, you need to properly configure your Dataproc cluster to install the `pandas` library. Please, see the relevant information in [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/tree/master/python) and the [official GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/python-configuration). As I told, I am not sure if it will work, but it could be a possibility. If necessary, [install `pyarrow`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/arrow_pandas.html) although my advice will be to first create a small POC instead

Comment: It's fixed in Spark 3.4+, though undocumented. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-39689 and https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/37107.