# Apache Spark CSV Write from a DataFrame with Windows New Lines (CRLF)

Tags: csv, apache-spark, newline

I'm running Apache Spark 3.1.2 in a Unix-based cluster to prepare CSV files for a Windows based ingestion system. When the Windows system ingests the CSV file created by the cluster's Spark CSV export, it fails to parse csv because the new lines are `LF` `\n` Unix Style new lines while the Windows system is expecting `CRLF` `\r\n` style line endings.

Is there a way to configure the Apache Spark CSV exporter to write with windows based new lines despite operating in a unix environment? Is there perhaps a scala tool that can be run after the CSV write that can convert the file to windows new lines before export to the windows system?

I've seen the `.option("lineSep", "\r\n")` but I believe that's for READING ONLY.

Comment: Why do you think that lineSep (if there is such an option) is for reading only? From what I've seen,  all the reading/writing options work both ways.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67090580/linesep-option-with-spark-2-4
Also, if you try to use \r\n, it says that option only supports single characters. Also, documentation says that reading is treated separate from writing in this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ugly solution - if your fields are not escaped you can add \r to the last field
2. Still ugly - if your csv fields don't need escaping - no strange characters, you can build the lines manually by joining all columns with comma add \r at the end and write as text
3. postprocessing - save as csv, read as text, add \r to each line and save as text.
4. if files not too big - I guess they are not as you are going to transfer them to another machine for processing, you can use linux tools to add \r, `sed`, `perl`, or just `unix2dos` util

Comment: I used solution 3.

Answer (score 0):

I had to post-process the file. I coalesced it to 1 partition and wrote out the CSV, then used a Java BufferedReader to load the file line by line. I used a BufferedOutputWriter to then pipe the input stream line by line into the writer, injecting \r\n between each line... SO LAME.

Comment: You didn't have to coalesce - you could've done postprocessing in spark as well. With regular map or perhaps with mapPartition to make sure that headers stay in place.

Comment: coalesce makes it a single file (the payload receiver requires this, as well as the ability to consume the file in a MS Windows system.). If I used spark to map-write the file, Spark would have used system-based newlines, which would have been unix-style, the system used to write the CSV, no?

Comment: If you need single file anyway it doesn't matter of course. I meant that my 3rd solution can be done in spark - read as text, add \r, save as text. But as I said, if you need headers, then probably mapPartition is required to make sure the lines stay in the same order.

Comment: ah, so injecting the \r per line using spark to read it as a text file instead of CSV seems like a plausible approach. Can still `coalesce(1)` before writing out in this manner... but it still would coalesce to a single thread making spark moot.