# Removing new line (\n) and carriage return (\r) characters in CSV file for all columns in pyspark dataframe using AWS Glue

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am looking to remove new line (\n) and carriage return (\r) characters in CSV file for all columns while reading the file into a pyspark dataframe.
With spark options, I have tried the following ways referring to the Spark documentation:

1. Tried with linesep options for \r and \n but I am not able to eliminate both \n and \r even though in the documentation there is an option for "\n\r" but 'lineSep' can contain only 1 character.

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option('delimiter',"|").option('header','true').option('linesep', "\r").load(input_path)
```

2. Tried with escape option as below:

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option('delimiter',"|").option('header','true').option('escape', "\\").load(input_path)
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990177/replace-new-line-n-character-in-csv-file-spark-scala